# I wanted my pregmatch to check for 6 different words on different lines. /s not working

Tags: regex

I wanted my `preg_match` to check for 6 different words on different lines. I have used `/s` keyword but it is not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: Don't you feel the question is unclear? Please provide an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

`/s` is invalid regex (unless the forward slash is escaped). You should be using `\s`, which is used to represent white space. Similar representations always use the backward slash.

For further reading, [check out regex characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)!